# How to properly check if a Set is empty

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, set

I've come with a question regarding the best way to check if a Javascript **Set** is empty. According with [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), there is no a straightforward method to check or get Set items.

I think it happens same with **Map**.

I've come up with some ideas (Node.js), but I'm not quite sure what's better.

```js
const assert = require('assert');

const emptySet = new Set()
assert.strictEqual(![...emptySet].length, true)
assert.strictEqual(emptySet.values().next().value === undefined, true)
assert.strictEqual(emptySet.entries().next().value === undefined, true)

const twoItemsSet = new Set([ 'foo', 'bar' ])
assert.strictEqual(![...twoItemsSet].length, false)
assert.strictEqual(twoItemsSet.values().next().value === undefined, false)
assert.strictEqual(twoItemsSet.entries().next().value === undefined, false)
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
emptySet.size == 0
```

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/size)

Comment: How about `emptySet.size === 0`?

Comment: @ICW Seriously?? The "====" is not even a JavaScript operator.

Comment: @CrisP Some sarcasm never hurts. Huston will have a really hard time creating a coercion problem while comparing two ints, won't he?